# Is there an easy way to differentiate $y= \left(\frac{\tan(\sqrt{1-\log_2(3x)})}{\coth(x^3+2e^{x^4})}\right)^{\arccos(3x^2)}?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there any simple (clever) method to compute the differentiation of this function or just long rigorous method?

$$y= \left(\frac{\tan(\sqrt{1-\log_2(3x)})}{\coth(x^3+2e^{x^4})}\right)^{\arccos(3x^2)}$$

Comment: If $cth$ is the hyperbolic cotangent, you can replace $1/cth(...)$ with $th(...)$. It’s small but every little bit helps, as right now I can’t see any miraculous simplification.

Comment: I mean taking the logarithm of both sides would help a bit.. I know that this morally doesn't work because the argument of $\log$ must be $>0$, but it still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to stay as close as possible to your problem, consider
$$y=\Big[\tan \left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right) \tanh (g(x))\Big]^{h(x)}$$
$$\log(y)=h(x)\log\Big[\tan \left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right) ]+h(x)\log\Big[ \tanh (g(x))\Big]$$
$$\frac{y'}y=h(x)\frac{ f'(x) \csc \left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right) \sec \left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right)}{2
   \sqrt{f(x)}}+h'(x) \log \left(\tan \left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right)\right)+$$
$$h(x) g'(x) \text{csch}(g(x)) \text{sech}(g(x))+h'(x) \log (\tanh (g(x)))$$ Now, compute the terms $f'(x)$, $g'(x)$, $h'(x)$ and by the end (have fun meanwhile)
$$y'=y\times \frac{y'}y$$